# containsKey check for nested LinkedHashMap

Tags: java

I have a nested HashMap (2 levels). The top level is a date, and the second level can contain one of three enum strings and a integer:

```
HashMap<LocalDate, HashMap<String, Integer>> hashMap = new  HashMap<>();
```

I am looping over a list of java objects which have a attribute date with many dates repeated and a string attribute stringAttr which is enum to 'Red','Green','Blue'.  I am adding to the HashMap with:

```
if (hashMap.containsKey((a.startDate.toLocalDate()))) { // does date exist?
    if (hashMap.get(a.startDate.toLocalDate()).containsKey(a.getStringAttr())) { // does String also exist?
        previousValue = hashMap.get(a.startDate.toLocalDate()).get(a.getStringAttr()); //if date and String exist - set previousValue
     } else {
           previousValue = 0; // String does not exist
     }
  } else {
        previousValue = 0; // Date does not exist
}

hashMap.put(a.startDate.toLocalDate(), new HashMap(){{put(a.getStringAttr(), previousValue + 1);}});
```

This correctly results in a list of unique dates but the inner HashMap only ever lists one string.

What is wrong with the way I am trying to get Key/Value pairs into the inner HashMap?

Comment: Your last line overwrites whatever was associated with the key `a.startDate.toLocalDate()`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this line. Can you show some example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the inner Map associated with the outer key in all cases.  This eliminates all of the previously added mappings.  You should update the existing mappings when found and add mappings if they are missing.

Here is a naive version of what I think you're trying to do.

```
LocalDate date = a.startDate.toLocalDate();
String attr = a.getStringAttr();
// If the date is not a key, add it mapping to an empty Map
if (! hashMap.containsKey(date) {
  hashMap.put(date, new HashMap<String,Intger>());
}
// If the attr is not an inner key, add it mapping to 0
if (! hashMap.get(date).containsKey(attr)) {
  hashMap.get(date).put(attr, 0);
}
// increment
int previous = hashMap.get(date).get(attr);
hashMap.get(date).put(attr, previous + 1);
```

Comment: There must be a syntax error on the put statement?  hashMap.put(date, new HashMap<String,Intger>()); complains of a syntax error on the inner hashmap missing ; or )

Comment: Ignore last comment. Works perfectly.